# SQLKata - Nested queries - How can i write the code for my query in using sqlkata for sqlserver in c#?

Tags: sqlkata

How can i write the code for the below query in using sqlkata for sqlserver in c#?

```sql
SELECT [t0].Region
FROM ((select * from [dbo].Demo_ReportData )) AS [t0]
GROUP BY [t0].Region
ORDER BY [t0].Region ASC
offset 0 rows fetch next 50 rows only;
```

Answer (score 1):

To use the `offset fetch` syntax you have to set the `UseLegacyPagination` to **false** on the `SqlServerCompiler`.

```
var compiler = new SqlServerCompiler { UseLegacyPagination = false };

var innerQuery = new Query("Demo_ReportData");
var query = new Query().From(innerQuery.As("t0"))
    .GroupBy("Region")
    .OrderBy("Region")
    .Take(50);

var result = compiler.Compile(query);
var sql = result.Sql;
var bindings = result.Bindings;
```

Comment: Please don't forget the bool